# Convert 1:00:00 PM to 13:00:00

Tags: python-2.7, date, data-conversion

in python 2.7 do you know how convert `9/21/2017 1:00:00 PM` to `9/21/2017 13:00:00` ?

I have my data in a dataframe in a column `df['entime']` with this format :
`9/21/2017 1:00:00 PM`

I tried to convert my column with `df['entime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['entime'])`

And then change format : `df['entime'].strftime('%Y/%m/%d hh:mm:ss')`

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? We will need code to help you, otherwise google it.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Don't know. You should help close  this as "unclear".

Comment: `hh:mm:ss` is not valid Python time formatting

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer rather than in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Function apply :

```
pd.to_datetime(dftime['enttime']).apply(lambda x:x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
```